# difference between await Task(ReadFromIO) and await Task.WhenAll(task1,task2);

Tags: c#, async-await

I read in the book about the differences of the below.

```
private async Task GetDataAsync() {
var task1 = ReadDataFromIOAsync();
var task2 = ReadDataFromIOAsync();
// Here we can do more processing
// that doesn't need the data from the previous calls.
// Now we need the data so we have to wait
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
// Now we have data to show.
lblResult.Content = task1.Result;
lblResult2.Content = task2.Result;
}

private async Task GetDataAsync() {
var task1 = ReadDataFromIOAsync();
var task2 = ReadDataFromIOAsync();
lblResult.Content = await task1;
lblResult2.Content = await task2;
}
```

I understood whats happening in the first method's await statement. But for the second one, though I understood the logic I couldn't understand the pitfall of the second implementation compared to first. In the book, they mentioned that compiler rewrites the method twice. What I understood is because of the two await calls, there could be a time delay more than the first one as we separately call the await for each task here. Can someone explain me in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what point your book was trying to make but I agree with your initial guess at it's interoperation.

Potentially the issue is there could be a period of time where `lblResult` shows new data and `lblResult2` shows old data if `task2` takes longer than `task1` to process. In the first method you wait till both tasks finish then update both labels at the same time (and when you exit your method both get repainted on the screen a the same time). In the second method you update the first label then you give the message loop a opportunity to repaint the screen then some time later you update the 2nd label and have that value get updated on the screen.

I guess you would have a *slightly* more complex state machine for the 2nd example too but the overhead of that is negligible, I am confident the book was trying to point out the issue you and I both came up with.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what the first method is doing is this:

1. Start `task1`
2. Start `task2`
3. Asynchronously wait for `task1` **and** `task2` to complete

The second implementation does this:

1. Start `task1`
2. Start `task2`
3. Asynchronously wait for `task1` to complete.
4. **Once `task1` is complete**, resume execution and then asynchronously wait for `task2` to complete.

So with the second approach you are individually awaiting the results of each task rather than waiting for both tasks to complete. In the case where `task1` completes before `task2`, the code will resume execution and then return straight away, that will result in an extra context switch which may take extra time. Also for the case of multiple awaits the compiler may end up generating a more complex state machine, but the effect of that should be negligible.

In either case you are not using the result until both tasks are complete so the behavior of the application shouldn't be too different.